# How to import github project WebRTC.rs

Tags: github, rust, webrtc, rust-cargo

I am very new to Rust and found this package on cargo.io that is a Rust implementation of the javascript API WebRTC. Here's the link https://crates.io/crates/webrtc#toolchain. That said, I am having a trouble using the package as there is no documentation anywhere and I can't find anyone else who has used this package. I am totally lost right now. How can I get started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the instructions on the page: https://crates.io/crates/webrtc

If your Cargo.toml and webrtc are on the same directory level you can just paste the following into your Cargo.toml:

```
webrtc = { path = "webrtc", version = "0.0.6" }
```